# How can I record sound from Linux?

Tags: linux, audio, recording

I have Linux (ubuntu). And I would like to record a sound. Does anybody know how to do it? I tried to use "Sound Recorder" program which I found in "Sound & Video" menu. First I press "Record". In several seconds I press "Stop". After that the whole window becomes dark and program does not respond. Does anybody know why it happens and how this problem can be solved?

Comment: Sound hardware?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try install [Audacity](http://audacity.sourceforge.net/).

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 3):

Use [gnome-sound-recorder](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/SoundRecorder).

To install it with `apt`, type

```
$ sudo apt install gnome-sound-recorder
```

Comment: has no options no volume control or ability to chose the sound source of which mic

Answer (score 1):

If Sound Recorder does not work, maybe install Audacity and [try to record from that](http://audacity.sourceforge.net/manual-1.2/tutorial_basics_4.html)?

Answer (score 1):

Following [How to Record Streaming Audio in Ubuntu and other Linux Distributions](https://itsfoss.com/record-streaming-audio/),

1. the gnome-sound-recorder is *only* for recordings with the microphone. I tested it and could not record my system sound (say, the sound of the Firefox output).
2. Then I checked the audio-recorder which was said to be for system sound, and it worked to choose Firefox as the output. Also taken from the link above:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:audio-recorder/ppa 
sudo apt update sudo
apt install audio-recorder
```

[image]

This is just a shortened copy and paste from that worthy guide! Have a closer look there for screenshots and more.

Answer (score 1):

`parec` is a tool from PulseAudio

Make sure you also have installed `ffmpeg`

```bash
parec --format=s16le --rate=44100 --device=alsa_output... | ffmpeg -f s16le -ar 44100 -ac 2 -i - output.mp3
```

Answer (score 0):

[mhWaveEdit](http://gna.org/projects/mhwaveedit) is another one you can try. It's less featureful than Audacity, but more reliable in my experience.

I don't know why Sound Recorder would hang. I've never experienced that before.

Answer (score 0):

As a simple audio recording software there is [Krecorder](https://apps.kde.org/krecorder/) but that is not package on many distributions.
Else you have [Kwave](https://apps.kde.org/kwave/) which can record, play back, import and edit many sorts of audio files including multi channel files. It's a bit more complete and is a Qt alternative to Audacity.

```
apt install kwave
```

Answer (score 0):

Open Broadcast Studio

```bash
sudo apt-get install obs-studio
```

Turns out I was getting noise via the mic input. Obs has level meters and controls for each input allowing precise control over what is being recorded.

As a bonus, obs has the ability to record any specific window which means you can continue to use your computer, watch the recording, watch the recorder or whatever while you record.

Note: Debian 12/Bookworm